# How to iterate switch case from a certain value to a certain other value

Tags: java, concurrency, enums, switch-statement

I do know Java, but switch case... Let's just say I've avoided using them, I don't really like them as a structure.

But now I'm forced to use them for choosing a channel on a concurrency problem. I just wouldn't know to change from the switch that I've been explained to an if-else, in this case.

So I have a range of cases, from 1 to N-1. First 4 I know what the cases are, they each do different things.

From 5 to N-1, all of them do the same, only difference is, if it's the case 7, the value it has to evaluate is P+7, and so on.

Can I somehow use a loop for that? N can get as big as 100000, it'd be plain bad doing it by hand.

Closer I've get to what I look for [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

when it says:

```
for (Planet p : Planet.values()) {
System.out.printf("Your weight on %s is %f%n", p, p.surfaceWeight(mass));
}
```

But I don't need to iterate every value, just from 5 to N-1.

Please tell me if I haven't explained myself, which would be the usual thing. English is my second language.

edit: I'm not 100% sure I could manage the cases properly enough, so I'm afraid of using default since it's concurrency code, I'd rather use a set of values I can define.

Comment: It hasn’t to do with English being your second language. The entire question is confused. Your are saying something about `switch` statements, then about a *concurrency problem*, and finally about *loops*. None of these artifacts has a relationship to the other. Well, besides that you might see them when programming in Java.

Comment: Holger, I think he explains the problem quite well. He is assigning behaviors to values, which has two common solutions: use a switch, or use an enum. An enum is poor because of the quantity of values, but he's afraid of using a switch because of a concurrency issue.

Comment: you can also leave the `break` out, and the cases will roll into each other.

Comment: @corsiKa: you still didn’t explain what the loops have to do with it which make up half of the question.

Comment: I've added more code to the post because I couldn't edit on comments, if it's way too specific please tell me and I add/edit it.

Ok there is a concurrency problem somewhere else in the code. This is CSP which means message passing, just (I think) a bit specific.

So there are channels. I need to solve the problem of 5 method, each does one thing so it can properly work. I have 5 conditions, one for each method. This is what defines what channels can send the info.

BUT one of the methods has an array of conditions. So I need an array of channels. So I need a case for every channel/condition

Comment: So, @Holger I need the loop for a number of cases inside the switch, but not for every case, so I can't use default, and I can't use a loop INSIDE a case. I need (afaik) a case for every conditions.

It goes for a given that there are several ways of solving this, with queues and what not. But arrays is the closer I have because of the explanations I've got and the previous code I've worked with, which solved this exact problem but with monitors (and I also used arrays, so I've been told to use them in this solution aswell).

Comment: @Holger Using loops would be necessary in the enum solution to iterate over the enums. As stated, though, the sheer quantity of enums makes that solution impractical.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a switch case with a default, storing the value to eliminate concurrency issues

```
final int val = getConcurrentValue();
switch(val) {
    case 1: doThingOne(); break;
    case 2: doThingTwo(); break;
    case 3: doThingThree(); break;
    case 4: doThingFour(); break;
    default: doCommonThing(CONSTANT_VALUE_P + val);
}
```

Alternatively, if you wrap this in a method (which greatly increases reusability, you end up eliminating the concurrency problem.

```
static void operate(int val) {
    switch(val) {
        // copy switch statement from above
    }
}

// elsewhere
import com.example.util.Functions;

void foo() {
    Functions.operate(getConcurrentValue());
}
```

Comment: Yeah that's the thing. It's exactly that, only that it's not a constant value.

Like, for each value of the switch in that moment, that's what's going to be added.

If it's case 6, I want 6 to be added, I'm not sure but I think your first example doesn't do that.

What I got so far: Ok I can't add enough code here, not enough characters.

This is the array:

final boolean[] posiciones=new boolean [4+Gruas.MAX_P_GRUA+Gruas.MIN_P_GRUA];

Comment: I'll add it to the post ok?